# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Error al insertar Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Buen dia! he creado 5 tablas e insertado datos en las mismas. Luego de esto cree en una la FOREIGN KEY en la tablas y me salta un error..

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jugos_ventas`.`#sql-15e0_9`, CONSTRAINT `facturas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`DNI`) REFERENCES `tabla_de_clientes` (`DNI`))
```

Mi al crear la tablas es:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_DE_CLIENTES(
DNI varchar(11) NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(100) NULL,
DIRECCION_1 varchar(150) NULL,
DIRECCION_2 varchar(150) NULL,
BARRIO varchar(50) NULL,
CIUDAD varchar(50) NULL,
ESTADO varchar(2) NULL,
CP varchar(8) NULL,
FECHA_DE_NACIMIENTO date NULL,
EDAD smallint NULL,
SEXO varchar(1) NULL,
LIMITE_DE_CREDITO float NULL,
VOLUMEN_DE_COMPRA float NULL,
PRIMERA_COMPRA bit NULL);

CREATE TABLE TABLA_DE_PRODUCTOS(
CODIGO_DEL_PRODUCTO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_DEL_PRODUCTO varchar(50) NULL,   
TAMANO varchar(10) NULL,
SABOR varchar(20) NULL,
    ENVASE varchar(20) NULL,
PRECIO_DE_LISTA float NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TABLA_DE_VENDEDORES(
    MATRICULA varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE varchar(100) NULL,
    PORCENTAJE_COMISION float NULL,
    FECHA_ADMISION date NULL,
    VACACIONES bit NULL,
    BARRIO varchar(50) NULL);     

 CREATE TABLE FACTURAS(
    DNI varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    MATRICULA varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    FECHA_VENTA date NULL,
    NUMERO int NOT NULL,
    IMPUESTO float NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS_FACTURAS(
    NUMERO int NOT NULL,
    CODIGO_DEL_PRODUCTO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CANTIDAD int NOT NULL,
    PRECIO float NOT NULL);
```

Luego en cada una de estas tablas inserte datos.. y después recién cree la PRIMARY KEY en cada uno asi:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLA_DE_CLIENTES ADD PRIMARY KEY (DNI);
ALTER TABLE TABLA_DE_PRODUCTOS ADD PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO_DEL_PRODUCTO);
ALTER TABLE TABLA_DE_VENDEDORES ADD PRIMARY KEY (MATRICULA);
ALTER TABLE FACTURAS ADD PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO);
ALTER TABLE FACTURAS ADD FOREIGN KEY (MATRICULA) REFERENCES TABLA_DE_VENDEDORES(MATRICULA);
ALTER TABLE FACTURAS ADD FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES TABLA_DE_CLIENTES(DNI);
```

Solo tengo error con

```
ALTER TABLE FACTURAS ADD FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES TABLA_DE_CLIENTES(DNI);
```

y no entiendo como puedo arreglarlo.

Comment: Al parecer en la FACTURAS tienes un DNI que no existe en TABLA_DE_CLIENTES, y por eso no te deja crear la llave

Comment: @Pipe Sí que el campo `DNI` está en las dos tablas, fíjate, es el primer campo de ambas

Comment: @Lili A mí me funciona todo correctamente: https://dbfiddle.uk/01u_pAP4

Comment: Acabo de ejecutar tu script tal cual lo tienes y se ejecuta sin problema. Se crean todas las tablas y posterior genera las claves primarias y relaciones.

Comment: Lili... me refiero es que tienes un dato dentro de la tabla FACTURAS en la columna DNI que no existe en los datos de la TABLA_DE_CLIENTES... si quieres crear una relacion, los datos actuales deben cumplir con esa relacion... Las columnas si existen... lo que debes revisar son los valores de las tablas. Si lo haces con tablas vacias seguro funciona... pero como dices que las tablas ya tienen datos, ahi debe estar el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias ahi lo corregi!!